# Need to use UISearchController without UITableViewController like a UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

So the scenario is that i'm implementing a searchbar on top of a mapView. So my class isnt UITableViewController. Previously it was using searchDisplayController, but since that is depreciated, i want to avoid using it. the search display controller was using UITableViewDataSource to manipulate table rows and such.

Can i still make rows appear on top while i search? the tutorials i can find for UISearchController are using UITableView. I want table rows just to display me my search result and disappear when i select a row and the search bar should resigns as well.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

EDIT: i am currently using a searchbar made from the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you need a design like a list, best option is a tableview. You can add a tableview below your search bar, hide it initially and then display it once user selects the searchBar for searching.
I have attached the screenshot for the storyBoard and here is the code to handle the hide and unhiding of tableview[image]

Here is the code:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    tableViewForSearch.isHidden = false

}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    tableViewForSearch.isHidden = true
}
```

These are searchBar delegates, they are quite descriptive. Don't forget to set the searchBar delegate to self.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replying. After a lot of tinkering around, I agree with you that this is the right direction as well, but i'm still struggling on how to manage a tableview manually on top of a view(which holds a mapview) and make it only appear when searchbar becomes first responder and disappears when its not

Comment: Ok, will it help if I attach the storyboard image and also corresponding code to hide the tableview when the searchBar is activated? Will update the answer in some time

Comment: Sure, much appreciated!

Comment: Updated my answer. Check @TaimoorAbdullahKhan

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

By using UISearchBar delegates you can achieve your task.

Step1: Add UISearchBar to your view from show object library.

/Users/rajesh/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-10-05 at 11.17.14 AM.png

Step2: Add UISearchBar outlet to your viewcontroller class.

`@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!`

Step3: Conform UISearchBar delegate to your viewcontroller class.

```
    `searchbar.delegate = self`
```

Step4: Use all UISearchbar delegate methods you will finish your scenario.

`@available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool` // return NO to not become first responder

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when text starts editing

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool // return NO to not resign first responder

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when text ends editing

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) // called when text changes (including clear)

@available(iOS 3.0, *)
optional public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool // called before text changes


@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when keyboard search button pressed

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when bookmark button pressed

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when cancel button pressed

@available(iOS 3.2, *)
optional public func searchBarResultsListButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when search results button pressed


@available(iOS 3.0, *)
optional public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can already use UISearchBar delegate methods. The issue i'm facing is UISearchController doesnt have a search display like UISearchDisplayController has. So i need to be able to connect it with a table. So the direction of the solution i can think of is somehow making a tableview appear when the searchbar becomes firstresponder. I need help with that

Comment: @TaimoorAbdullahKhan how have you solved it in the end? am up against the same :/